# Implement a second onclick function to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I tried to implement a second onclick function to a button, but the only thing it made, was either to multiply and randomize numbers he should implement or didnt even work from the beginning.

```
    var total = 0;

      function add(value) {
        total += value;
        document.getElementById("result").value = total;
      }

      function cw_add() {
        let value = 1;
        total += value;
        document.getElementById("currywurst").value = total;
      }
```

The two codes look like this /,

```
        <button type="button" onclick="add(3.00)" style="background-color: red;" class="select_button">
            Currywurst mit Brot
            <span class="preis_button">
                3,00€
            </span>
        </button>
```

and the button looks like this /.

I tried to rewrite the code several time, but found no solution whatsoever. Even tried it with chatgpt but that didn't worked either.

Comment: I've launch your code, it works just fine. Check console for error msgs or try to provide full html page code example

Comment: By the way, result & currywurst should be as <input> elements on your page, are they?

Comment: So you want to call two functions with one click?